# How can i pass an operator as an argument to a function, i am doing a calculator in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, arguments, calculator

```
 public int MainOperationSimplifeid(char operatoru)
    {
        if (beforeoperation == 2)
        {
            a2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = "";
            result = a1 operatoru a2;
            //   textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
            a1 = 0;
            a2 = 0;
        }
        beforeoperation++;
        return result;
    }
```

> a1, a2 - represents two numbers in the program and result is the answer for the >operation peformed

i am thinking of using one single character or some other like argument that reduce all my operators used else where in the program

but i cant get the +, * as replace to a char between two integers. :(

Can you guys please help which inbult function or argument can replace all my operator to a single variable , so that i can pass that as my argument.

Thanks for going through my question :)

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing can be done with delegates. The built in delegate type `Func<T1, T2, T3>` represents code that accepts two parameters and returns a result.

```
public int MainOperationSimplifeid(Func<int, int, int> operatoru)
{
    if (beforeoperation == 2)
    {
        a2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        result = operatoru(a1, a2);
        //   textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        a1 = 0;
        a2 = 0;
    }
    beforeoperation++;
    return result;
}
```

Then you can call the method with a lambda:

```
var addResult = MakeOperationSimplifeid((x, y) => x + y);
var multResult = MakeOperationSimplifeid((x, y) => x * y);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't make that, because the compiler needs the operator to compile the program. So, as I can see, the solution could be a `enum`, Something Like this:

```
Enum Operator {
     Addition, Substraction, Multiplication, Division 
};

public double MainOperationSimplified(Operator operatoru)
{
    if (beforeoperation == 2)
    {
        a2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = "";

        switch (operatoru) {
            case Addition:
               result = a1 + a2;
               break;
            case Substraction:
               result = a1 - a2;
               break;
            case Multiplication:
               result = a1 * a2;
               break;
            case Division:
               result = a1 / a2;
               break;
            default:
               result = 0;
               break;
        }

        a1 = 0;
        a2 = 0;
    }
    beforeoperation++;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, still i am expecting a little easy answer or to mean more direct answer. Switch case of 4 would look nice but i am thinking of a very bigger operator stack , supplying my own operators for a better functinality