# perform calculation based on the operator passed as method parameter

Tags: c#, generics, operators, code-reuse

I'm trying to do arithmetic operations based on the operators passed as method parameter. I can perform this in many ways but problem is I've a datatable to be operated upon. I cannot pass particular data row as I have many datarows to be operated on.

**What I have done:** I know this can be done in delegate style. something like in the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44333156

```
public int MainOperationSimplifeid(Func<int, int, int> operatoru)
{
    if (beforeoperation == 2)
    {
        a2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        result = operatoru(a1, a2);
        //   textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        a1 = 0;
        a2 = 0;
    }
    beforeoperation++;
    return result;
}
```

I know, I can also achieve this by using enum or switch or even by method overloading. But my code is already huge and complex with multiple supporting methods. So I don't want to add more complexities.

**What I need:** Can I do it something like this?

```
void MethodName(DataTable dt, int operand, char op)
{
   //few lines of code
   dt.SomeRowName1 = (double)dtRowValue op operand;
   //few lines of code
   dt.SomeRowName2 = (double)dtRowValue op operand;
   dt.SomeRowName3 = (double)dtRowValue op operand;
   //few lines of code
}
```

I want to achieve this in a very generic way (code reusability) rather than doing method overloading or switch for different operators and writing same lines of codes again and again.

Comment: A datatable row need to be index like an array dt["name"] or dt[index]

Comment: @jdweng: it would be like this dt["name"].

Comment: Your `MainOperationSimplifeid` is a monster. It looks like a function, but it gets a value from the UI, changes a value on the UI, has side-effects on result, beforeoperation, a1 and a2, and has an arbitrary constant, that isn't named. Methods and functions should do one thing and do them well and functions shouldn't have side-effects.

Comment: And furthermore, I don't understand the question.

Comment: it's really hard to get what you want to achieve, as your two codes are completely different. Your desired one doesn't do any UI-things, while the former one has this crazy `beforeOperation`-thing. This makes it impossible for us to give you any idea about how to transform the first one to the latter. Last your first code has a delegate accepting two ints, while your second one only has a single int.

Comment: There is [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math), but I'm not sure if it is helpful. You should probably see if there is some other approach for whatever goal you have. I would probably try convert the DataTable rows to actual typed objects as early as possible, and use methods on these objects for as much functionality as possible.

Comment: Hi @MakePeaceGreatAgain I'm least bothered about the UI-things. Also the `beforeOperation` thing is the one I tried but couldn't achieve what I need. So, I skipped it. Now I'm looking for an approach where I can just pass an arithmetic operator as a string or char to the method and perform operation with the operand. I'm performing operation only with the rows of data table which will contain double or int values.

Comment: okay, one step back: what is **the** operand? In case of plus/minus... you allways have two of them, e.g. 1 + 2. Please elaborate on what the function should actually do, and how you want to call it.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain: I want to keep it Simple : this function gets a datatable. datatable contains rows. I want to replace few row values like this:
`dt.DataRow = dt.DataRow / operand;`
`dt.DataRow = dt.DataRow * operand;`
Division or Multiplication depends on the operator I pass to this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for the operator method with reflection, then create a delegate from it.

```
static Func<T, T, T> FindOperator<T>(string op)
{
    var m = typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                     .First(mi => mi.Name.EndsWith($"op_{op}"));
    return (Func<T, T, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, T, T>), m);
}

// Usage
FindOperator<int>("Division")(7, 2);
FindOperator<double>("Addition")(7.1, 2.3);
```

This method should work for numeric types since .Net 6.

If you are concerned about efficiency, you can cache the results.

If you want to know which values "op" can take, please check the long "Implements" list in the document of the corresponding type --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.

It can be more generic by specifying the type of each parameter in the operator.

```
static Func<TSelf, TOther, TResult> FindOperator<TSelf, TOther, TResult>(string op)
{
    var m = typeof(TSelf).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                     .First(mi => mi.Name.EndsWith($"op_{op}"));
    return (Func<TSelf, TOther, TResult>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TSelf, TOther, TResult>), m);
}
```

---

Here's another example of using expressions and reflection to create operator methods, this can also be used in .Net Framework.

```
static Func<T, T, T> CreateOperator<T>(string op)
{
    var l = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var r = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var m = typeof(Expression).GetMethod(op, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null,
                                         new Type[] { typeof(Expression), typeof(Expression) }, null);
    var b = (Expression)m.Invoke(null, new object[] { l, r });
    return (Func<T, T, T>)Expression.Lambda(b, l, r).Compile();
}

//Usage
CreateOperator<int>("Multiply")(7, 4);
CreateOperator<float>("Divide")(3.6f, 1.25f);
```

The supported op values can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression#binary-arithmetic-operations

Comment: hi shingo. in this line `FindOperator<int>("Division")(7, 2);` I tried to pass `Division` and `Multiply`, but the code breaks. As mi.Name doesn't end with such word. Can you guide on this?

Comment: It requires .net 6, are you using .net framework?

Comment: yes! I'm using .Net framework 6

Comment: There's no .net framework 6, the latest version is 4.8.1. I've added a new method that can be used in .net framework >= 3.5.

Comment: yes agreed! it is .Net 6. I was using .Net 4.7. But both the methods you have given is working perfectly fine. When I re created a new project with .Net 6, first two methods worked. But the last method worked with the project I was working on. Thanks a ton!!!